# How to find the number of SQL queries executed from a LINQ to entities statement

Tags: c#, .net, linq, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4.1

I am looking to review my code for inefficiencies, is there a way to easily profile controller actions... perhaps printing all the sql statements that are executed?

Answer (score 3):

Can you use the [SQL Server Profiler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181091.aspx)?  I used this recently for my web application so I could see what queries were being executed by the identity of my application.

Answer (score 2):

This is a very cool tool [linqpad](http://www.linqpad.net/)
to view the produce sql

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend [MVC-Mini-Profiler](https://code.google.com/p/mvc-mini-profiler/). Works very nice and gives you the results in your browser. See also [Scott Hanselman's article](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/NuGetPackageOfTheWeek9ASPNETMiniProfilerFromStackExchangeRocksYourWorld.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

As the others said, SQL Profiler gives you the queries.

However - if you want more detail into whats going on with EF (since you tagged as Entity Framework) there is this great tool:
http://efprof.com/

There are other alternatives as well:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/gg490349.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I've had good results using [EF Tracing and Caching Provider](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/EFProviderWrappers) (for which a community branch can be [found on NuGet](http://nuget.org/List/Packages/CommunityEFProviderWrappers.EFTracingProvider)). Once set up, all SQL executed is sent to the Windows Debug output, so you can just use DbgView or similar to see what's going on.